# How do I average row values using Python and create a new data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, mean

I'm currently working with a data frame.

[Data](https://github.com/Shambok97/Sample-Data-/blob/main/data.csv)

The year goes all the way to 2022. What I'm trying to do is create a new dataframe that has two columns.

1)Year
2)Average of the 'extent' column for those corresponding years.

So to illustrate-

| Year | Average Extent |
| --- | --- |
| 1978 | 12.487 |
| 1979 | 12.320 |

and so on until 2022.

I tried using pandas .groupby method and some others such as

`new_df = df[['year','Extent...']].copy()`

but I'm unsure how to group the rows for each year and give the average yearly 'extent' value for those corresponding years.

I hope this makes sense.

Any advice/tips will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are tring to create a new df, by averaging all values of extent of specific years. Is this your problem?

Comment: Instead of 3 columns representing a date, I recommend a single pd.DatetimeIndex: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

You can then simply `.resample("Y").mean()`. If you add some reproducible data, we can show you

Comment: Alternatively, do a `.groupby("Year")["Extent ..."].mean()`

Comment: @AdityaSoni Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Thanks. So would it be ` new_df  = df.groupby(`Year')['Extent ...'].mean() ?

Comment: Pretty much, but make sure to fill in the right column name for Extent...

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as I'm getting an attribute error @Chrysophylaxs

Comment: We can't help you properly without some example data that we can use to test code

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs This is a sample data. [Data](https://github.com/Shambok97/Sample-Data-/blob/main/data.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should run out of the box:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shambok97/Sample-Data-/main/data.csv")

# Removing whitespace at the ends of the column names for convenience
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

out = df.groupby("Year")["Extent (10^6 sq km)"].mean()
```

out:

```
Year
1978    12.48700
1979    12.31956
Name: Extent (10^6 sq km), dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question, try this piece of code for desired output

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'your_data_path/data.csv')
# group by year and get the average sell for each year
df_grouped = df.groupby('Year')['Extent (10^6 sq km)'].mean()
# convert the grouped dataframe to a new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df_grouped).reset_index()
# Rename the column 
final_result = new_df.columns = ['Year', 'Average Extent']
final_result #see the desired output
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `agg` function to get the Average Extent for each year and then use the `reset_index()` function to convert the result to a dataframe:

```
final_result = df.groupby('Year').agg({'Extent (10^6 sq km)':'mean'}).reset_index()
final_result.columns = ['Year', 'Average Extent']
```

This will give you the same output as above.